# DOMDocument spoil text

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I have some text in cyrillic: "Сегодня мы делали анонс", but after

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadHTML('Сегодня мы делали анонс');
```

and after that I run

```
$dom->saveHTML();
```

I receive `&ETH;&iexcl;&ETH;&micro;&ETH;&sup3;&ETH;&frac34;&ETH;&acute;&ETH;`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The encoding set in the DOMDocument constructor is overridden when `loadHTML` is called. Instead, it needs to be specified in the HTML content that is loaded:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<meta charset="utf-8">Сегодня мы делали анонс'); // specify the input encoding

$dom->encoding = 'UTF-8'; // set the output encoding
print $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement);

// [...] <p>Сегодня мы делали анонс</p> [...]
```